# how to kill the GPU based on the PID?

Tags: python, gpu, nvidia, pid, kill

I tried

```
kill -9 7169 <br/>
```

but this does not work. 
this is run by pytorch cuda train

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you mean, your python program that's using GPU. You need to find type C processes. There is 1 with PID 7169.

Now, do:

```
sudo kill -9 7169
```

Comment: do you get any log output? or the tasks are still just there?

Comment: im running it on pycharm. task are still there and can not stop anything. if you are familier with pytorch or deep learning. https://github.com/SlowMonk/ssd.pytorch_/blob/master/train.py
 output = net(images)  <------------program just stop

Comment: pycharm, pytorch all of these are completely irrelevant. This is a linux command and nothing else, I told you to add a log from the terminal, not what model you're training.

Comment: no log at all . actually except pid 7169. The sudo kill is working.
the strange thing is pid 7169 is using both gpu 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

Try nvidia-smi

```
nvidia-smi | grep 'python' | awk '{ print $3 }' | xargs -n1 kill -9
```